# getting confidence intervals from coeftest?

Tags: r

Is there a way to get coeftest to report confidence intervals? Or a command that will calculate confidence intervals from coef results?

dummy data:

```
library(lmtest)
data("mtcars")
testmodel <- glm(am ~ vs, data = mtcars, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))
testcoef <- coeftest(testmodel)
testcoef
z test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -0.69315    0.51640 -1.3423   0.1795
vs           0.69315    0.75593  0.9169   0.3592
```

Answer (score 2):

would that help?

```
library(lmtest)
data("mtcars")
testmodel <- glm(am ~ vs, data = mtcars, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))
testcoef <- coeftest(testmodel)

confint(testcoef)
coefci(testmodel)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following @Will, you could use `cbind` to combine `coeftest` with `coefci`

```r
cbind(coeftest(testmodel), coefci(testmodel))
cbind(coeftest(testmodel), confint(testmodel))  ## profile CIs (more accurate)
```

Or use `broom::tidy`:

```r
library(broom)
tidy(testmodel, conf.int = TRUE)  ## profile CIs (the only option)
```

If you have multiple models, it's convenient to use `purrr::map_dfr` to combine the results:

```r
data(mtcars)
m1 <- glm(am ~ vs, data = mtcars, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ mpg)
(list(vs = m1, mpg = m2)
  |> purrr::map_dfr(tidy, conf.int = TRUE, .id = "model")
)
```

Comment: That's awesome. If I had more than one of these models, is there a good package for reporting them out together? I've tried huxreg in my non-dummy data script, but I keep running into problems trying to report the CI (or even the pvalue) from these coeftest results